# In Linux terminal, how to delete all files in a directory except one or two

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, filesystems

In a Linux terminal, how to delete all files from a folder except one or two?

For example.

I have **100** image files in a directory and one **`.txt`** file.
I want to delete all files except that **`.txt`** file.

Comment: except which one or two?

Comment: You'd better show some pattern of how the exceptions should look like. Otherwise we will be able just to give a very general answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From within the directory, list the files, filter out all not containing 'file-to-keep', and remove all files left on the list.

```
ls | grep -v 'file-to-keep' | xargs rm
```

To avoid issues with spaces in filenames (remember to never use spaces in filenames), use `find` and `-0` option.

```
find 'path' -maxdepth 1 -not -name 'file-to-keep' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Or mixing both, use `grep` option `-z` to manage the `-print0` names from `find`

Comment: This might be problematic if there are spaces in the filenames.

Comment: Works. I must be in the current directory to successfully execute this command. right?

Comment: I tried this command as `sudo ls directory/directory/directory1/ | grep -v 'readme.txt' | xargs rm` but didn't work. I have to run this command on many directories. Suppose I `directory` has siblings `directory2, directory3`.

Comment: @Bilal For the command starting with `ls`, yes, it will do the job in the current directory. If you use the `find` command, then you can list as many directories as you want as `'path'`.

Comment: In option 1, `grep` needs to have `--line-regexp` argument here, b/c otherwise `/bin/w` will match `/bin/which`.

Answer (score 9):

In general, using an inverted pattern search with grep should do the job. As you didn't define any pattern, I'd just give you a general code example:

```
ls -1 | grep -v 'name_of_file_to_keep.txt' | xargs rm -f
```

The `ls -1` lists one file per line, so that grep can search line by line. `grep -v` is the inverted flag. So any pattern matched will NOT be deleted.

For multiple files, you may use egrep:

```
ls -1 | grep -E -v 'not_file1.txt|not_file2.txt' | xargs rm -f
```

*Update after question was updated:*
 I assume you are willing to delete all files except files in the current folder that do not end with `.txt`. So this should work too:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name "*.txt" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: epic. clean answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

find supports a `-delete` option so you do not need to `-exec`. You can also pass multiple sets of `-not -name somefile -not -name otherfile`

```
user@host$ ls
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt 6.txt 7.txt 8.txt josh.pdf keepme

user@host$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name keepme -not -name 8.txt -delete

user@host$ ls
8.txt  keepme
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `not` modifier to remove `file(s)` or `pattern(s)` you don't want to delete, you can modify the `1` passed to `-maxdepth` to specify how many sub directories deep you want to delete files from

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name "*.txt" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

You can also do:

```
find  -maxdepth 1 \! -name "*.txt" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

In bash, you can use:

```
$ shopt -s extglob  # Enable extended pattern matching features    
$ rm !(*.txt)       # Delete all files except .txt files
```