# Bash script: variable output to rm with single quotes

Tags: bash

I'm trying to pass parameter to rm in bash script to clean my system automatically. For example, I want to remove everything except the *.doc files. So I wrote the following codes.

```
#!/bin/bash
remove_Target="!*.txt"
rm $remove_Target
```

However, the output always say

```
rm: cannot remove ‘!*.txt’: No such file or directory
```

It is obviously that bash script add single quotes for me when passing the variable to rm. How can I remove the single quotes?

Comment: this is asked before:
[In Linux shell, how to delete all files in a directory except one or two][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779328/in-linux-shell-how-to-delete-all-files-in-a-directory-except-one-or-two

Comment: The quotes are just part of the error message. The problem is that the pattern doesn't match any files, so it is passed literally to `rm`.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. You are right. The single quotes are parts of the error message from rm. I change my script to rm !(*.txt). It now works in the command line but fails in bash script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using Bash

Suppose that we have a directory with three files

```
$ ls
a.py  b.py  c.doc
```

To delete all except `*.doc`:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ rm !(*.doc)
$ ls
c.doc
```

`!(*.doc)` is an extended shell glob, or `extglob`, that matches all files except those ending in `.doc`.

The extglob feature requires a modern `bash`.

#### Using find

Alternatively:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '*.doc' -delete
```